# Error when I want to display a row from sqlite

Tags: android

In my app I want to display data from sqlite. 
When I press the button Show Info, I want to put the records that returns function getInfo in the textView. This is my code:

```
btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
        final TextView txtNume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNume);
        final TextView txtPrenume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrenume);
        final TextView txtTelefon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefon);
        final TextView txtAdresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtadresa);
        final TextView txtAdresaEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        final TextView txtDataNasterii = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDataNasterii);
        final TextView txtSex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSex);
        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Pacienti pacienti = pacientiDB.getInfo(text);
                if (pacienti != null) {
                    pacienti.setTelefon(txtTelefon.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setPrenume(txtPrenume.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setNume(txtNume.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setAdresa(txtAdresa.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setDataNasterii(txtDataNasterii.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setEmail(txtAdresaEmail.getText().toString());
                    pacienti.setSex(txtSex.getText().toString());
                    }}

});
```

This is the function getInfo:

```
public Pacienti getInfo(String text) {
        Pacienti returnPacient = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {

            cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PACIENTI_NAME
                    + " WHERE prenume = '" + text + "'", null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                int indexTelefon = cursor.getColumnIndex("telefon");
                int indexPrenume = cursor.getColumnIndex("prenume");
                int indexNume = cursor.getColumnIndex("nume");
                int indexAdresaEmail = cursor.getColumnIndex("adresaEmail");
                int indexSex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Sex");
                int indexAdresaBuletin = cursor.getColumnIndex("AdresaBuletin");
                int indexDatanasterii = cursor.getColumnIndex("dataNasterii");
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String nume = cursor.getString(indexNume);
                    String prenume = cursor.getString(indexPrenume);
                    String Telefon = cursor.getString(indexTelefon);
                    String AdresaEmail = cursor.getString(indexAdresaEmail);
                    String Sex = cursor.getString(indexSex);
                    String AdresaBuletin = cursor.getString(indexAdresaBuletin);
                    String DataNasterii = cursor.getString(indexDatanasterii);

                    returnPacient = new Pacienti();
                    returnPacient.setNume(nume);
                    returnPacient.setPrenume(prenume);
                    returnPacient.setTelefon(Telefon);
                    returnPacient.setAdresa(AdresaBuletin);
                    returnPacient.setEmail(AdresaEmail);
                    returnPacient.setDataNasterii(DataNasterii);
                    returnPacient.setSex(Sex);
                    cursor.moveToNext();

                } while (!cursor.isAfterLast());
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        return returnPacient;
    }
```

But it didn't work. I receive this error and I don't understand why, because I verify that I have data in the database:

```
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.example.medicaldoi.ShowInfo$1.onClick(ShowInfo.java:53)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-14 10:35:33.478: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me please!

Comment: what is your 53. line in ShowInfo.java?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked using breakpoints to see what variable is null? Where is the line 53 in this code?

Where do you instantiate the variable "text" you use in the function getInfo? Are you sure this variable is not null?

Comment: This is the line 53: Pacienti pacienti = pacientiDB.getInfo(text);

Comment: The variable "text" is not null. I put a Log and it display me the value. @Yoann

Comment: What do you use to debug? Eclipse?

Comment: So just put a breakpoint on this line and check what is null, it can only be pacientiDB or text.

Comment: you have right, pacientiDb was null. Thanks. And now I receive this error: Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 8

Comment: I resolve the problem. In my database the name of the column it's "adresaBuletin" and in my code I put "AdresaBuletin". It's about case sensitive. But the value still don't appear in the textView. I put breakpoint, everything it's ok, no error but when I run the app the textView is blank. I don't understand why....

Comment: Thank you for all. Now it display me the value from database. I made a stupid error. In the method on click I put  pacienti.setNume(txtNume.getText().toString()); of course it was wrong because if I want to display me the value I have to write something like this: txtNume.setText(pacienti.getNume());